# Delete Directory removes last directory in string if its empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, directory.delete

The below Sub searches through some folders and deletes any empty ones (Unless the folder is called Bars or Backup)

sPath is set to `c:\temp\working\` and the folders that should be scanned and deleted if empty are sub-directories of `Working`

The sub does the job however if it gets to the point where all the sub-directories are empty and have been removed then the folder `Working` is then deleted which is not what I need to happen.

Any suggestions on how to stop this, or do i need to recreate the directory if it gets to that stage (not ideal)

```
  Public Sub DeleteEmptyFolders(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim SubDirectories() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(sPath)
    For Each strDirectory As String In SubDirectories
        DeleteEmptyFolders(strDirectory)
    Next
    If Not (UCase(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath)).Contains("BACKUP")) Or (UCase(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath)).Contains("BARS")) Then
        If Directory.GetFiles(sPath).Length + Directory.GetDirectories(sPath).Length = 0 Then
            Directory.Delete(sPath)
            MsgBox("Deleting empty folder: " & sPath)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first approach to solve the problem could be to pass the starting root and do not delete the directory if it is the starting root

```
Public Sub DeleteEmptyFolders(ByVal sPath As String, ByVal sRoot As String)

    Dim SubDirectories() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(sPath )
    For Each strDirectory As String In SubDirectories
        DeleteEmptyFolders(strDirectory, sRoot)
    Next
    If Not (UCase(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath)).Contains("BACKUP")) Or (UCase(Path.GetDirectoryName(sPath)).Contains("BARS")) Then
        If Directory.GetFiles(sPath).Length + Directory.GetDirectories(sPath).Length = 0 Then
            if sPath <> sRoot Then
                Directory.Delete(sPath)
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting empty folder: " & sPath)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Call with

```
DeleteEmptyFolders("D:\temp", "D:\temp")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the fact the second variable is also a path

Comment: My bad, removed the sRoot from GetDirectories where is not needed